# Eclipse, Maven & Spring Roo 1.2.4.RELEASE: Missing artifact org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.annotations:jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, spring-roo

I am trying to create and compile a project using Spring Roo 1.2.4... 
I am using:
- Spring Roo 1.2.4.RELEASE
- Spring STS 3.4.0.RELEASE
- Maven 3.0.5

Spring Roo console seams to work. But Maven dependencies has an error into Eclipse IDE.

Missing artifact org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.annotations:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE

I created my project using Spring STS wizard... and my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ar.gov.pjn.scw.migrator</groupId>
    <artifactId>scw_migrator</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <roo.version>1.2.4.RELEASE</roo.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <oracle.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>    
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ROO dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
          <version>${oracle.version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <!-- NB: do not use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 issue  -->
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <!--
                      Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added 
                      as default in the compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added 
                      as default in the test-compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/main/java are added in the test-compile 
                      goal if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true
                    -->
                    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it after config "spring roo release repository" in my nexus without having successfully.... I resolved it cleaning my user maven repository... and forcing maven to update... as It did't download the JAR file, I placed it where it should go... and it's working

Comment: How did you clean the user maven repo?

Comment: I simply backuped my .m2/repository folder and then I deleted it to start downloading all maven dependencies locally again.
Then I checked to find .jar dependency downloaded into .m2/repository/{jarparth}/...jar

It's not the best solution but it's working on my machine perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't already done it, try updating the project with regard to Maven.

In Eclipse Kepler, right-click on the project, then `Maven > Update Project...` and then make sure your project is checked under `Available Maven Codebases`, and that `Update project configuration from pom.xml` is checked, then select `OK`.

For older versions of Eclipse, you just right-click on the project, then `Maven`, and then I believe `Update project configuration`.

Each of these should signal to Eclipse that the `pom.xml` has been updated, and that it needs to be reexamined and to download any dependencies.

Comment: Thks einnocent, I forgot to say that i did it before.